# Iterate an ArrayList with Iterator in a particular order without sorting the list

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of `Product` (class) and I need to iterate through the list in order by `product.price`. I don't want to sort the list, just to iterate through it in a particular order.

Comment: What do you mean "scroll" through an `ArrayList`? Scrolling is something done on graphical components, which an `ArrayList` is not. Do you mean iterate?

Comment: Yes, I used the wrong word.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 streams allow you to do something like this:

```
mylist.stream()
      .orderBy(Comparators.comparing(Product::getPrice))
      .forEach(product -> {
           // do something with the product
           System.out.println(product);
      });
```

This assumes that your class `Product` has a method `getPrice()`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this without sorting the list would be to copy this list to another one and then sort that copy in the desired order.